# change language in gTTS using subprocess

Tags: python, gtts

```
import os
import subprocess
from gtts import gTTS


class Record:
    def __init__(self, file, path):
        self.file_name = f'{file.split(".")[0]}.mp3'
        self.file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        self.out_path = os.path.join(path, self.file_name)

    def create_recordings(self):
        subprocess.call(['gtts-cli', '-f' + self.file_path, '-o' + self.out_path])


path = r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\create_recordings'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        Record(file, path).create_recordings()
```

**what im trying to do:**

change the language in the subprocess.call command
ive tried adding 'lang=' + 'en-uk' after the self.file_path, but it returns an error:

```
Usage: gtts-cli [OPTIONS] <text>

Error: Invalid value for "<text>": <text> and -f/--file <file> can't be used together
```

so im not really sure how to change it to add a different language

what id really like is if i could pass the language to the Record class and use that in the subprocess.call command

theres a lot of languages to change it to, but heres all the english ones that show from using gtts-cli --all in the command line:

```
  en-au: English (Australia)
  en-ca: English (Canada)
  en-gb: English (UK)
  en-gh: English (Ghana)
  en-ie: English (Ireland)
  en-in: English (India)
  en-ng: English (Nigeria)
  en-nz: English (New Zealand)
  en-ph: English (Philippines)
  en-tz: English (Tanzania)
  en-uk: English (UK)
  en-us: English (US)
  en-za: English (South Africa)
```